# expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE true instead

Tags: netlogo

I want to write an evacuation with leader code in net-logo but i have this error (AND expected input to be a TRUE/FALSE but got the number 0 instead.)the error came from function (follow_leader). my project is that i evacuate  an environment and evacuate it with the nearest leader from the crowd . the code is not perfect that because  iam knew to netlogo .

this is my code

```
globals[  goal-x goal-y n number leader
  percent_of_leader wall
window
door largecircle]

patches-own [path?
 obstacle
 goal]
turtles-own [direction
  fast?
  fear?
  leader?
is-leader?
  follower
  other-nearby]


to setup
    clear-all
set-default-shape turtles "person"
  ;create-turtles 50 [ set color yellow ]
  ;ask turtles [fd random 13 ]
  drwa-walls


    ask n-of population patches with [ pcolor = black]
   [sprout 1
   [ set color white
     set size 0.9
     set shape "person"
    set leader? false
      ;set follower self
   if   xcor < 9 and ycor > 9 [set heading 0]
     if xcor >= 9  and ycor >= -10[set heading -90]
   if xcor > -12 and ycor < -10 [set heading 90]
     if  xcor <= -8  and  ycor > -10  and ycor < 0 [set heading 180]
  ]]

    choose-leaders

 end


 to choose-leaders
   ask turtle 6
     [
     set leader? true
     set color yellow
     set size 1
      set shape "default"
     set leader self
      set xcor 3
      set ycor 10
      set heading 0
   ]
 end


to go
  move-for

  ask turtle 6[move-to-exit1
  fd 1 ]

    ask turtles with [shape = "person"][

    ifelse  (xcor < 9 and ycor > 9 ) [follow_leader] [move-to-exit1]
 if xcor >= 9  and ycor >= -10  [move-to-exit2]
     if xcor > -12 and ycor < -10 [move-to-exit3]
     if xcor < -12 and ycor < -10 [move-to-exit3]
    if xcor <= -8  and  ycor > -10  and ycor < 0 [move-to-exit4]
    ;avoid obstcao
    ; avoid_obstacles
 ;ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = blue
    ; [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; We see a blue patch in front of us. Turn a random amount.
      ;[ fd 1 ]                  ;; Otherwise, it is safe to move forward.

   ; ifelse not is-patch? patch-ahead 3 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 3 =
 ;blue or not is-patch? patch-ahead 2 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 2 =
 ;blue or not is-patch? patch-ahead 1 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 =
;blue
    ;[lt random-float 360 ]
   ;[fd 1]
      ;  while [patch-ahead 1 = nobody]
   ;[
     ;lt random-float 360
   ;]
  ;ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = blue
     ; [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; We see a blue patch in front of us. Turn a random amount.
      ;[ fd 1 ]

      ; ifelse not is-patch? patch-ahead 3 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 3 =
 ;white or not is-patch? patch-ahead 2 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 2 =
 ;white or not is-patch? patch-ahead 1 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 =
;white
   ; [lt random-float 360 ]
   ; [fd 1]
        ;ifelse not is-patch? patch-ahead 3 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 3 =
 ;green or not is-patch? patch-ahead 2 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 2 =
;green or not is-patch? patch-ahead 1 or [ pcolor ] of patch-ahead 1 =
;green
    ;[lt random-float 360]
   ; [fd 1]

  ]
   reset-ticks
   tick


  end
to rt-random
   while [patch-ahead 3 = nobody]
   [
     rt random 360
   ]
end

to avoide
ask turtles [
if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = green
[lt random 360 fd 1]

]
end



to avoid_obstacles ;; all obstacles set as green patches
 let i 1
 while [[pcolor] of patch-ahead i != blue ]
 [set i (i + 1) ]
  if ([pcolor] of patch-ahead i = blue)
   [
    ifelse [pcolor] of patch-at-heading-and-distance (heading - 20) i + 1 = blue
    [
        ifelse [pcolor] of patch-at-heading-and-distance (heading + 20) i + 1 = blue
        [
            ifelse random 1 = 0
            [ rt 360 ]
            [ lt 360]
        ]
        [ rt 360 ]
    ]
    [lt 360]
   ]
 end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to bounce
  if [pcolor] of patch-at dx 8 = blue [
    set heading (90)
  ]
  if [pcolor] of patch-at 0 dy = blue [
    set heading (-90)
  ]
end
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to move-for
  ask turtles with [shape = "person"][fd 1]


end
to drwa-walls
  draw-exit1
  draw-exit2
  draw-exit3
  draw-exit4
  ;rows x
  ask patches with [pxcor <= 30 and pxcor >= 0 and pycor = -10]
  [set pcolor blue]
    ask patches with [pxcor >= -30 and pxcor <= 0 and pycor = 9]
  [set pcolor blue]
  ;coilmn
  ;ask patches with [pycor <= 9 and pycor >= -10 and pxcor = 0]
  ;[set pcolor green]
   ;ask patches with [pycor <= 4 and pycor >= 0 and pxcor = 0]
  ;[set pcolor green]
  ;circle shape

  ask patch -14 -9 [
  set largecircle patches in-radius (2)
]
;set color of largecircle patches green
ask largecircle [
  set pcolor green
]
   ask patch 16 16 [
  set largecircle patches in-radius (2)
]
;set color of largecircle patches green
ask largecircle [
  set pcolor white
]
end

to draw-exit1
  ;exits at top of concourse area, where turtles will leave
  set goal-x -1
  set goal-y -30
  ask patch goal-x goal-y [
    sprout 1 [ set pcolor red
      set shape "square"
    ]
  ]
end

to draw-exit2
  set goal-x -1
  set goal-y 30
  ask patch goal-x goal-y [
    sprout 1 [ set pcolor red
      set shape "square"
    ]
  ]
end

to draw-exit3
  set goal-x -30
  set goal-y -6
  ask patch goal-x goal-y [
    sprout 1 [ set pcolor red
      set shape "square"
    ]
  ]
end

to draw-exit4
  set goal-x 30
  set goal-y 4
  ask patch goal-x goal-y [
    sprout 1 [ set pcolor red
      set shape "square"
    ]
  ]
end

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;exit goals;;
to move-to-exit1
  facexy -1 30
end

to move-to-exit2
  facexy 30 4
end

to move-to-exit3
  facexy -1 -30
end

to move-to-exit4
  facexy -30 -6
end
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;to follow-leader
     ;if not leader?           ;; we only want to ask non-leaders
    ;[let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? and distance myself < 3] ;; find nearby leaders
    ;if any? nearby-leaders                                            ;; to avoid 'nobody'-error, check if there are any first
   ;  [ set heading (towards min-one-of nearby-leaders [distance myself]) ]]              ;; then face the one closest to myself
  ; end
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
to follow_leader
  let nearby-leaders turtles with [is-leader? and distance myself < 10] ;; nearby leaders
  if any? nearby-leaders[
    face min-one-of nearby-leaders [distance myself]
  fd 0.5]

end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please only provide relevant code. For NetLogo, that is usually the procedure that throws the error (or doesn't work correctly etc) and whichever procedure calls it.

In your case, this is the procedure you mentioned:

```
to follow_leader
  let nearby-leaders turtles with [is-leader? and distance myself < 10]
  if any? nearby-leaders[
    face min-one-of nearby-leaders [distance myself]
  fd 0.5]
end
```

So the `and` that is throwing the error must be `[is-leader? and distance myself < 10]` (also, please state which line if you know it). My guess would be that you haven't initialised the variable is-leader? so it is 0 (the default value) instead of either `true` or `false`.

If this is the problem, wherever you creates turtles, initialise with `set is-leader? false`

Comment: to follow_leader
  let nearby-leaders turtles with [is-leader? and distance myself < 10] ;; nearby leaders
  if any? nearby-leaders[
    face min-one-of nearby-leaders [distance myself]
  fd 0.5]

end

Comment: this is the code with the error and when i did what you suggest it didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Error message? If so, where? Some behaviour that is different than you expected (and if so, what did it do and what did you expect)? Something else? Also, please show the piece of code where you did what I suggested, in case that's the problem.